# How to get CPC from Google Adwords Traffic Estimator Service in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-ads-api

I've been pouring over the google adwords api docs and I can't figure out how to format the selector to retrieve CPC information. I am using the google-adwords-api gem.  Below is the method I'm working on inside my Adwords api module.

```
def self.traffic_estimator_service keyword

    if !@adwords #If not already authenticated, do it first
        Adwords.authenticate()
    end

    traffic_estimator_service = @adwords.service(:TrafficEstimatorService, API_VERSION)


    selector = {
        :xsi_type => 'KeywordEstimateRequest',
        :match_type => 'EXACT',
        :keyword => keyword
    }

    data = traffic_estimator_service.get(selector)


    puts '---------------------------------'
    puts data.inspect
    puts '---------------------------------'

end
```

Of course I never get to the data2.inspect line because of the api errors.  ie:

```
AdsCommon::Errors::UnexpectedParametersError (AdsCommon::Errors::UnexpectedParametersError: [:match_type]):
```

I've moved things around and tried multiple things inside the selector hash.  Can someone give me an example of what this selector hash should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selector = {
  :campaign_estimate_requests => [
    {
      :xsi_type => 'CampaignEstimateRequest',
      :ad_group_estimate_requests =>        {
        :xsi_type => 'AdGroupEstimateRequest',
        :keyword_estimate_requests => [
          {
            :max_cpc => {
              :xsi_type => 'Money',
              :micro_amount => 1_000_000
            },
            :xsi_type => 'KeywordEstimateRequest',
            :keyword => {
              :xsi_type => 'Keyword',
              :text => keyword,
              :match_type => 'EXACT'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```